# Django - Administrador El ORM no me deja hacer una relacion uno a mucho entre dos tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server, django, django-models

Estoy aprendiendo Django y estoy conectandome a SQL Server pero no puedo hacer la relación **uno a muchos** como se muestra en la imagen.

Tengo la tabla `it_empresas` con el campo `cod=primary_key`. En la tabla `it_departamento` con el campo `cod_empresa=ForeignKey` y el campo `cod_departamento= Primary_key`.

Esto me permite grabar en la tabla `it_departamentos` varios registros de un mismo `cod_empresa` con distinto código de departamento, pero si quiero agregar otro `cod_empresa` con un `cod_departamento` existente de la otra empresa no lo permite, la imagen es más clara.

Estos son los modelos:

```
class it_empresas(models.Model):
    cod = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20 ,null=False, blank=False, verbose_name='Codigo de Empresa')
    rut_legal = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    comuna = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    fono = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    def nombre_empresa(self):
        return "{} - {}  - {}".format(self.cod, self.rut_legal, self.razon_social)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_empresa()
    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        verbose_name = 'it_empresa'
        verbose_name_plural = 'it_empresas'
        db_table = 'it_empresas'
        ordering = ['cod']
    
class it_departamentos(models.Model):
    cod_empresa = models.ForeignKey(it_empresas, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='cod_empresa', verbose_name='Codigo Empresa')
    cod_departamento = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20,blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='Codigo de Departamento')
    nombre_departamento = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    def departamento(self):
       return "{} - {} - {}".format(self.cod_empresa, self.cod_departamento, self.nombre_departamento)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.departamento()
    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        verbose_name = 'it_departamento'
        verbose_name_plural = 'it_departamentos'
        db_table = 'it_departamentos'
        ordering = ['cod_empresa', 'cod_departamento']
        #unique_together = (('cod_empresa', 'cod_departamento'),)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué significa "no me lo permite". Tira un error? Una excepción? Cuál es el mensaje?

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, me muestra un mensaje, no se cae el administrdor, el mensaje dice "Ya existe It_departamento con este Codigo de Departamento."

Comment: Pues tiene sentido. En la configuración de  `cod_departamento` tienes `primary_key=True`. Siendo una llave única, no se pueden repetir. Lo que tú quieres, al parecer, es tener una *llave primaria compuesta* por `cod_empresa` y `cod_departamento`, donde la combinación sea lo que hace único al registro. Sólo así podrás tener una estructura como tu ejemplo de excel. La otra manera es dejar la tabla sin llave primaria pero tendrás que implementar lógica para evitar ambigüedades.

Comment: Gracias por responder Arriel, Te cuento que desde sql server se graban de manera correcta los registros, tal cmo se ve en la planilla excel. Por otro lado quité el Primary_Key del campo cod_departamento, pero al hacer esto ahí si se cae el administrador de Django diceindo que no existe el campo id y sigo sin entender, si sql server lo hace bien ¿porque Django no?, gracias por ayudarme, soy nuevo en esto .

Comment: Alguna ayuda de como solucionar el mensaje que muestra el administrador de Dajngo?, se agradece mucho la ayuda